# Is there an access modifier combination or pattern limiting to the class and its containing class?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

The [list of access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) gives us `public`, `private`, `protected`, `internal`, and `protected internal`. When writing a nested class, I find myself wanting a magic modifier combination (unlikely) or coding pattern that gives me `private` or `protected`, but where the containing class also has access. Is there such a thing?

Example - a public property only code in the class or its container class can set:

```
public class ContainingClass {
    public class NestedClass {
        public int Foo { get; magic_goes_here set; }
    }

    void SomeMethod() {
        NestedClass allow = new NestedClass();
        allow.Foo = 42;                     // <== Allow it here, in the containing class
    }
}

public class Unrelated {
    void OtherMethod() {
        NestedClass disallow = new ContainingClass.NestedClass();
        disallow.Foo = 42;                  // <== Don't allow it here, in another class
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that? Again, probably not literally with an access modifier unless there's a magic combination I missed on the page linked above, but some pattern I can use to get it in effect if not reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IFooable
{
    int Foo { get; }
}
public class ContainingClass 
{
    private class NestedClass : IFooable
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }
    public static IFooable CreateFooable()
    {
        NestedClass nc = new NestedClass();
        nc.Foo = 42;
        return nc;
    }
    void SomeMethod() {
        NestedClass nc = new NestedClass();
        nc.Foo = 67;                        // <== Allow it here, in the containing class
    }
}
public class Unrelated 
{
    public void OtherMethod() 
    {
        IFooable nc = ContainingClass.CreateFooable();
        Console.WriteLine(nc.Foo);
        nc.Foo = 42;                        // Now it's an error :P
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I **knew** there was a way to do it with interfaces. The missing piece for me was the builder. Thanks!